# How to ngRoute between two pages

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

Trying to use ngRoute to route between two pages, main.html and second.html. Using angular version 1.7. The index.html default to the correct main.html but will not route to second.html when clicking the link titled Second. [This](https://www.z1labs.com) is the page I'm trying to do this on.

This is the code in the app.js file.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('/', { 
        templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
     })
    .when('/second', { 
        templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
        controller: 'secondController'
    })
});

myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$log', 

    function($scope, $log) {

}]);

myApp.controller('secondController', ['$scope', '$log', 

    function($scope, $log) {

}]);
```

The html has these divs.

```
<div class="container">

    <div ng-view></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue changing the href to ng-href inside the header tag and by using a value of #! instead of #. Below is my new nav links inside my header.

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a ng-href="#!"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li><a ng-href="#!/second"><i></i> Second</a></li>
        </ul>
```

I simply replicated what I saw done [here](https://itnext.io/handling-angularjs-routing-with-angular-route-ngroute-a8e6facaf3f9).